# Azure Devops: Gates on a Release Pipeline: Select running agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there a way to set up the agent that runs a gate, in specific the one that is calling an Azure function from a post-deployment Gate?

In our case the Function it's been published behind a security setup and it does not have public access. We have an agent pool enabled to run the task but it seems the option doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, Gates in the release pipelines are agentless as per [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/azure-function?view=azure-devops).

In our case, we needed to config the function to be available from the internet. A nice to have feature in the future releases for Azure DevOps.